# sort by subject in privatemsg

Tags: privatemsg

Is there any possibility to sort all the messages by subjects? For example, there is a button on the main page "send a message to author". Subject from the sender is defined as "main page". If several users send message with this subject, can i see in my mailbox one subject "main page" and then see the list, who wrote it?

[image: privatemsg sort]

Answer (score 0):

Messages in the inbox can be filtered by subject.  To do so, if you are on the default path (`messages`), just click the blue link for "Subject" at the top of the table.

Alternately, if you want to always filter by subject, you can change the messages link to this:
`messages?sort=asc&order=Subject`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Maybe my question was incorrect. But, i want to do next. I've got some messages with same subjects. I want to group them into one row in table. 
For example, there is one subject and two messages with the same subject in one row.

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/d02f0131274249293221a76f340a8405.png

Comment: There's no way to do this out of the box with Private Message.  You could look at the functions in `privatemsg.pages.inc` and write a custom sort.